# Create List of Remaining Values from List after generating Random numbers in android

Tags: android, random

I am creating "Jacks Or Better" game in android, in that i am generating 5 random numbers from list of 52 numbers and storing it to a list now i want to store remaining 47 numbers in other list so that i can again generate random numbers from the list of remaining numbers. i did following code,

```
Random rng = new Random();
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    while (true) {
        Integer next = rng.nextInt(52);
        if (!generated.contains(next)) {
            generated.add(next);
            openCards.add(CardArray.get(next));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is for generating 5 random numbers and storing it into a list but i don't have any how to store remaining 47 numbers into other list.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want SecureRandom instead.

Reimplement CardArray as a CardSet and remove from it as you "pull" the cards. You can add cards back to the set or you can simple clone the CardSet before use depending on how you want to optimize space vs compute.